# Developing a Function Which Can Compute Any Linear Combinations of a Given Set of Equations

Tags: functions, algebraic-manipulation

I usually work a lot with equations and their linear combinations. So I thought that I may develop a function which take a given set of equations and compute a desired linear combinations of those equations. But I don't know what is the best way to do this. Here is my little effort

```
f[{c1_, Eq1_}, {c2_, Eq2_}] := c1*Eq1[[1]] + c2*Eq2[[1]] == c1*Eq1[[2]] + c2*Eq2[[2]]
Eq1 = a == b
Eq2 = c == d
f[{1, Eq1}, {1, Eq2}]
```

and the output is

```
a + c == b + d
```

here are my questions

1- Is this approach good?

2- How can I make the number of arguments of my function arbitrary?

3- I also noted that my function does not work when I give an identical equation like `1=1` to it. Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: What do you mean by making the arguments arbitrary?. Note that `1==1` simply evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @Feyre: I mean to give any number of equations as you want! I knew that `1==1` evaluate to true, but I wanted to able to add `1` to both sides of equation by this function too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this, this way you can put in any amount of equations:

```
f[c_, eq_] := Plus @@ (c.eq[[All, 1]]) == Plus @@ (c.eq[[All, 2]])

eq1 = a == b;
eq2 = c == b;
eq3 = d == a/b;
f[{2, 1, 3}, {eq1, eq2, eq3}]
```

> `2 a + 2 c + 3 d == (3 a)/b + 3 b`

You can't store a an equation which automatically evaluates such as `1==2` or `1==1`, as it will just store the `False` or `True`. To do this, you'd have to store the relevant equations as a list, which can be mixed with actual equations.

```
eq4 = {1, 1};
f[{2, 1, 3, 6}, {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4}]
```

> `6 + 2 a + c + 3 d == 6 + (3 a)/b + 3 b`

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the nice answer. :)